# How do I bind to an image from an api endpoint?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently, I have an app where I want to display a list of image thumbnails on my layout.

I'm able to get the json response from the api endpoint and deserialize it. Now, I have an image object and in that object, I have an image preview url (the thumbnail image). My question is how do I display a list of thumbnail images in my layout?

Here's the method that gets called to display images and some property setup:

```
private List<string> images;
public List<string> Images
{
    get { return images; }
    set { SetProperty(ref images, value); }
}

private async Task DisplayImages()
{
    var imageObj = await _mediaService.GetCatImages();


   //imageObj.Hits[i].PreviewUrl; <-- how to a reference to the previewurl but what property should it bind to?

}
```

Here's my layout at the moment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:flv="clr-namespace:DLToolkit.Forms.Controls;assembly=DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView"
             x:Class="MediaViewer.Views.ContentFolderMedia">

    <flv:FlowListView FlowColumnCount="3" SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="false"
            FlowItemTappedCommand="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}" FlowLastTappedItem="{Binding LastTappedItem}"
            FlowItemsSource="{Binding Images}" >

        <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" 
                XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>

    </flv:FlowListView>
</ContentPage>
```

Where the layout should look like an image gallery (hence why I'm using this third party library: https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls)

So, this line: `FlowItemsSource="{Binding Images}` should be where the binding occurs but I'm not sure to properly set the property so that it binds to the preview url and displays the image. It also makes me think... usually an image source is a name of a local image but if I'm hitting a url to see an image, do I need to do any conversion in my app to display the image from a url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the structure of the list returned by your service? Let's say it is `List<ImageObj`>.

First you need to change your Images type:

```
private List<ImageObj> images;
public List<ImageObj> Images
{
     get { return images; }
     private set { SetProperty(ref images, value); }
}

private async Task DisplayImages()
{
    Images = await _mediaService.GetCatImages()
                                .Select(x => x.Hit)
                                .ToList();
}
```

Then you've correctly bound your list to your `Listview`.
Now within the `DataTemplate` you need to add an Image bound to the url:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Image Source="{Binding PreviewUrl}" />
</DatatTemplate>
```

Comment: what is url in this case however? How can I make it it's tied with previewUrl above?

Comment: I edited the answer. I'm on mobile, not easy to write code though.

Comment: Thanks! It works, just the images are really slow to load up. I think maybe I should look into TheGeneral's advice about FFImageLoading. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`FFImageLoading`](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading) with a `FlowListView`

This will give you the ability to load the image from a url, caching, and fast loading.

Just add it to your `DataTemplate` and bind via the `CachedImage` `Source` property

```
Source="{Binding url}"
```

Comment: Sorry to bother again but do you know how to set the height of the image for FlowListView? I can't seem to set it to a particular height? The images are appearing small. Thanks!

Comment: @Euridice01 `HeightRequest` and `WidthRequest`

Comment: ok let me try again. I tried a MinimumHeightRequest but it wasn't taking. Thanks!